# Error while parsing JSON Object in Android

Tags: kotlin, gson, okhttp, interceptor, jsonapi-serialize

In my Android application, I want to fetch the details of the user's profile using the token that is sent in the header format, but I get the following errors

Specify the JSON Parsing Error:

```
java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhite space(JsonReaderjaval 406) at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.consumeNonE xecutePrefix(JsonReaderjaval 615) at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonR eader.java.544) at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader. peek(JsonRea derjava:435) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapt erFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFacto ry.java:251) at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConvert er.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40) at retrofit2.convertergson.GsonResponseBodyConvert er. convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27) at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java: 243) at retrofit.2.0 kHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java: 153) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run( RealCall.kt:519) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker( ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) at lava i itil rnnr•I irrpnt ThrparlPnnIFvpri rtnrW/nrkpr n in(
```

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapt erFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFacto ry.java:270) at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConvert erconvert(GsonResponseBodyConverterjava:40) at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConvert erconvert(GsonResponseBodyConverterjava:27) at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java: 243) at retrofit2.0kHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java: 153) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run( RealCall.kt:519) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker( ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run( ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.javal 012) Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines. DiagnosticCoroutineContextExcep tion: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@acd6dc7, Dispatchers.Mainimmediate] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $ 
at
```

```
Network Module
```

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideInterceptor() = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
    level =
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideClient(
    timeOut: Long,
    @Named(NAMED_PING) ping: Long,
    session: SessionManager,
    interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor
) = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor { chain ->
        val token = runBlocking {
            session.getToken.first().toString()
        }
        chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().also {
            it.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, "$token")
            it.addHeader(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON)
        }.build())

    }.also { client ->
        client.addInterceptor(interceptor)
    }
    .writeTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .connectTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .pingInterval(ping, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(baseUrl: String, gson: Gson, client: OkHttpClient): ApiServices =
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
        .create(ApiServices::class.java)
```

}

ApiService

```
    @GET("profile/show_profile.php")
    suspend fun getInfoUser(): Response<ResponseInfoUser>
```

ResponseInfoUser

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class ResponseInfoUser(
    @field:SerializedName("date")
    val date: String?, // 2023-09-02
    @field:SerializedName("email")
    val email: String?, // 
    @field:SerializedName("image")
    val image: String?, // 
    @field:SerializedName("name_family")
    val nameFamily: String? // mahdi
)
```

I also wrote in this way

```
data class ResponseInfoUser(
    @SerializedName("date")
    val date: String?, // 2023-09-02
    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String?, // 
    @SerializedName("image")
    val image: String?, // 
    @SerializedName("name_family")
    val nameFamily: String? // mahdi
)
```

HomeRepository

```
class HomeRepository @Inject constructor(private val api: ApiServices) {
    suspend fun getInfoUser() = api.getInfoUser()
}
```

MviHomeIntent

```
sealed class HomeIntent {
    object ShowInfoUser :HomeIntent()
}
```

HomeState

```
sealed class HomeState {
    object Idle : HomeState()
    object LoadingProfile : HomeState()
    data class ShowInfoUser(val profile: ResponseInfoUser) : HomeState()
    object Empty : HomeState()
    data class Error(val error: String) : HomeState()
}
```

HomeViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: HomeRepository) : ViewModel() {
    //Login
    val intentChannel = Channel<HomeIntent>()
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<HomeState>(HomeState.Idle)
    val state: StateFlow<HomeState> get() = _state

    init {
        handleIntents()
    }

    private fun handleIntents() = viewModelScope.launch {
        intentChannel.consumeAsFlow().collect { intent ->
            when (intent) {
                is HomeIntent.ShowInfoUser -> fetchingProfileUser()
            }
        }
    }


    private fun fetchingProfileUser() = viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = repository.getInfoUser()
        _state.emit(HomeState.LoadingProfile)
        when (response.code()) {
            in 200..202 -> {
                _state.emit(HomeState.ShowInfoUser(response.body()!!))
            }

            in 400..499 -> {
                _state.emit(HomeState.Error(""))
            }

            in 500..599 -> {
                _state.emit(HomeState.Error(""))
            }
        }

    }




}
```

BackEnd PHP

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

  require '../connection.php';
  
      $rawToken = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
      $token = preg_replace('/Bearer\s+|\[|\]/i', '', $rawToken);


     $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_subscribers WHERE token= :token";

  $resault=$connect->prepare($sql);
  $resault->bindParam(':token', $token);
  $resault->execute();

    while($row=$resault->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        
        $record["name_family"]=$row['name_family'];
        $record["email"]=$row['email'];
        $record["date"]=$row['date'];
        $record["image"]=$row['image'];

    }
        echo JSON_encode($record);

}
?>
```

[call Postman Api Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWvyP.png)

I also changed the received response for the data class, but the error was not fixed

```
data class ResponseInfoUser(
    @SerializedName("date")
    val date: String, // 2023-08-27
    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String, // 
    @SerializedName("image")
    val image: String, // http
    @SerializedName("name_family")
    val nameFamily: String // dggf
)
```

Comment: Handle the exception and log the JSON you're getting

Comment: How should I do this?

Comment: Your error is sort of self-explanatory: `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path`. You expect a JSON object (i.e. `{...}`), but actually you receive a List of JSON objects (i.e. `[...]`)

Comment: Thank you. Is the error related to api? Is there no way to solve the problem in Android?

Comment: @Noah; you can solve this by either adjusting your PHP code, or the Android app code. The cause for the `EOFException` is probably that your PHP code produces an empty response when no matching record is found. It should either produce valid JSON (e.g. `null`) or send HTTP 4... to indicate an error. For `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY` as jujka pointed out, the JSON structure is incorrect. Please verify that your PHP code really always responds with a JSON object `{ ... }`.